# Mod Rewrite Dynamic Paths (no query)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create redirects to content on my old site in the form of:

`domain.com/fiction/UNIQUE/book` to
`sub.domain.com/fiction/UNIQUE/book`

Not all pages on `domain.com` should redirect to `sub.domain.com`. Just the ones that contain `/fiction/`. `UNIQUE` is a dynamically generated `ID`.

So this should be simple to check for the existence of `domain.com/fiction/` and replacing with `sub.domain.com/fiction/` then adding the rest of the string `/UNIQUE/book`.

I have looked at Mod Rewrite and posts with `QUERY_STRING`, but my understating is limited and this appears to only be applicable with ?query style dynamically generated pages.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(fiction/.*)$ http://sub.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

`http://domain.com/fiction/UNIQUE/book` will get redirected to `http://sub.domain.com/fiction/UNIQUE/book`. `http://domain.com/scifi/UNIQUE/book` will not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Is your subdomain static or does it depend on the UNIQUE identifier?

In case it is static the following should do the trick:

```
# Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Do not rewrite real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*/ - [L]

# Your important rule goes here; Accepted as unique ids are alphanumeric strings
RewriteRule fiction/([A-Za-z0-9]*)/book http://sub.domain.com/fiction/$1/book
```

For more information the according [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is a great resource.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Maybe I had it in the wrong location. I have many redirects and the default WordPress rewrites in my .htaccess. The answer below worked.